# protobuf serializetostring in python ends with \x00, reparsing in C++ fails

Tags: python, c++, protocol-buffers

I have the following proto file :

```
// [START declaration]
syntax = "proto3";
...
// message from cloud to device
message Downstream
{
    // types
    message GetValues{}

    // fields
    uint32 TargetDeviceAddress=1;   
    oneof sub_message{
        Axis target_axis=2; // new axis values to set
        GetValues get_light=3; // get light sensor values
    }
}
...
// [END messages]
```

and use the following code in python to serialize protobuf data (to send it over the wire)

```
    downstream = RobotControlInterface_pb2.Downstream()
    downstream.TargetDeviceAddress = 1
    downstream.get_light.SetInParent()

    if downstream.IsInitialized():
        downstream_serialized = downstream.SerializeToString() #despite its name, returns the bytes type, not the str type.
        print(downstream_serialized)
        print(type(downstream_serialized))
```

The result is :

```
b'\x08\x01\x1a\x00
<class "bytes">
```

Trying to ParseFromString in C++ fails.
The python data is recived in C++ like:

```
std::string serializedPayload = (char*)message->payload;
control_interface::Downstream downstream_message;
if (downstream_message.ParseFromString(serializedPayload))
//Fails every time
```

But now the data changed to
[image]

Which is the same like "\x08\x01\x1a"!!!

How can this be solved ?

Comment: `std::string serializedPayload = (char*)message->payload;` this looks like you shoot yourself in the leg by invoking constructor expecting null-terminated string. If `payload` was indeed a pointer to C-style string then cast wouldn't be necessary here.

Comment: The seen data is correct. C  string `"\b\001\032"` ends with `\000`. What you see is zero-terminated string, the terminator is not shown.

Comment: On the other hand, if buffer pointed to by `payload` is indeed properly terminated with `\0` then `std::string` will turn out to be one char shorter because it treats it as an end.